# CSS Background to fit multiline text

Tags: css

My problem :

I have text without 
 and a max-width.
I want the background to fit exactly the width and height of the text not without empty space cause the text is breaking.
I try to remove that kind of padding-right...
HTML:

```
<div>
    <h1>bigword another big word</h1>
    <p>hello there what's up</p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div{
    background: #C00;
    max-width:157px;
}
```

Here is a jsFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/T8g89/1

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

If you only want the color around the text you should set the background color on the header the best thing I could tell you is remove the bg color from the div and put it on the h1.  Then set the h1 to inline, * Because headers tend to be block/inline-block elements which will cause that extra body.  Think of a block as a box *

```
div{
    max-width:157px;
}

h1{
    background: #C00;
    display: inline;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Hu8v6/

Comment: Sorry it would be too easy, I did precise I have some other text with it